# Menu Bootstrap não funciona Responsivo

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap

Menu com Bootstrap não funciona de forma responsivo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nome da Loja</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <header>
           <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Store</a>
                   <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">Menu</button>
              </div>

               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li><a href="#">Novidades</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Mais vendidos</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>

           </nav>
       </header>
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu arquivo Bootstrap.js está sendo carregado primeiro do que o arquivo jquery-2.1.3.min.js e por isso não está abrindo o menu.

- Caso um arquivo js dependa de outro, ele sempre precisa está abaixo, e sempre prudente colocar os arquivos jQuery primeiro, pois ele não depende de ninguém, e sempre a plugin que dependem dele.

Comment: Correto o problema está na declaração do js da página, o seu bootstrap.js está vindo primeiro, mas ele depende do jquery-2.1.3.min.js que está sendo declarado depois, pois isso ao clicar no menu hambúrguer não está abrindo.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Obrigado, Leonardo.

Mas, creio que tem algo muito errado.
Continua com o mesmo problema, porém quando eu clico ele fica marcado como fosse funcionar mas não executa o dropdown.

Comment: Não tem amigo você esqueceu do navbar-fixed-top,

Comment: Aqui deu certo, você está carregando os arquivos css ?